# Using regex to check subsequences of string

Tags: python, regex, string, substring

I am trying to check if expressions with substrings of length 3 contain exactly one `c` character. That is, every substring of length 3 in a string must contain a `c` character. For example:

Strings such as: `"a", "cc", "bbc", "cabcbbca", "acaacbacbb", "abcabcabc"`, all have exactly one `c` in their substrings of length 3. If any substrings have less than length 2, then they are valid regardless.

However, strings such as: `"caaa", "bbcaacbcaac"`, fail this requirement as they contain substrings of length 3 that don't contain exactly one `c` character.

So far I have made a quick python program which checks this:

```
# Testing expressions
expressions = ["a", "cc", "bbc", "cabcbbca", "acaacbacbb", "abcabcabc", 
               "caaa", "bbcaacbcaac"]

# Getting substrings of a certain length
def get_substrings(string, sublen):
    substrs = []

    for i in range(len(string)):
        if len(string[i:i+sublen]) == sublen:
            substrs.append(string[i:i+sublen])

    return substrs

# extracting valid expressions
def get_valid_expression(expressions, minlen, char_to_check):

    valid = []

    for string in expressions:

        # if string is less than min length, then it is already valid
        if len(string) < minlen:
            valid.append(string)

        else:

            # get the subtrings
            lst = get_substrings(string, minlen)

            # Check if the substring contains exactly one of the characters
            if all(substring.count(char_to_check) == 1 for substring in lst):
                valid.append(string)

    return valid

print("Valid expressions with all substrings of length 3 containing exactly one c:")
print(get_valid_expression(expressions, 3, "c"))
```

Which returns the valid expressions`['a', 'cc', 'bbc', 'cabcbbca', 'acaacbacbb', 'abcabcabc']` from the original list.

Is their a way with regex I can do this? I believe generating a regular expression to search this would be better and not require much code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
^.{0,2}$|^[^c]{0,2}(c[^c]{2})*c[^c]{0,2}$
```

[Try it](https://regex101.com/r/7jZW1f/1)

To test for a, b, c only, use:

```
^[abc]{0,2}$|^[ab]{0,2}(c[ab]{2})*c[ab]{0,2}$
```